# mysql database date field datatype

Tags: php, mysql

Hope somebody can advise on the following:

I have created a table into my database which has a coloumn with datatype defined as DATE. The normal MySQL date order is YYYY-MM-DD, however I need to enter it in format DD-MM-YYYY.

I am using php to insert data into my table, and I was wondering at what point should I convert the date format.

To summerize, I am asking the following:

1. Is it possible to insert into MySQL database where field is formatted as DATE, a date in format DD-MM-YYYY instead in format YYYY-MM-DD?
2. If not possible, can I convert a value posted from PHP in format DD-MM-YYYY into the format YYYY-MM-DD using the MySQL syntax or I should use PHP to post the value in YYYY-MM-DD format?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Have you made any research? Have you tried anything?

Comment: Look into the function `str_to_date()`, http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date.

Comment: Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal effort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would use [`STR_TO_DATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) in your `INSERT` to convert the date to the ANSI standard date format.

```
INSERT INTO `table` (`date`) VALUES (STR_TO_DATE('01-05-2013','%d-%m-%Y'));
```

You can then use [`DATE_FORMAT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) to convert the ANSI standard date to the format you want.

Comment: As you told for insert  and if i wants to fetch in format of  day-month-year into a table. then how it works?

Answer (score 0):

A date is always stored in the same manner in the DB.

When inserting you have to give the DB a format that it can parse as date. And when reading from the DB you can format the date in any way you like.

So you have to format your data before inserting into the correct format. Otherwise the DB can't store it as date.

Answer (score 0):

You can go to different mysql website and get this answer. For Example:

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-date-time-functions.htm

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE('21,5,2013','%d,%m,%Y');
```